# Как запретить прокрутку страницы если навел на div в котором можно прокручивать элементы?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведение на `div` и когда прокручиваем `scroll` не передвигался. И точно также на пустой `div`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #EDEEF0;
}

.list {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="list">
    <div class="element">Element_1</div>
    <div class="element">Element_2</div>
    <div class="element">Element_3</div>
    <div class="element">Element_4</div>
    <div class="element">Element_5</div>
    <div class="element">Element_6</div>
    <div class="element">Element_7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="list"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот как вариант:

```js
var $document = $(document),
  $body = $('body'),
  $scrolable = $('.list');

$scrolable.on({
  'mouseenter': function() {
    $body.addClass('noscroll');
  },
  'mouseleave': function() {
    $body.removeClass('noscroll');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #EDEEF0;
}

body.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="list" id="list">
    <div class="element">Element_1</div>
    <div class="element">Element_2</div>
    <div class="element">Element_3</div>
    <div class="element">Element_4</div>
    <div class="element">Element_5</div>
    <div class="element">Element_6</div>
    <div class="element">Element_7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="list"></div>
</body>
```

Вариант без `overflow: hidden;`:

```js
$('.list').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
  var scrollTo = null;
  if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
    scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * 0);
  } else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
    scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
  }
  if (scrollTo) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #EDEEF0;
}

body.noscroll {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.list {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="list" id="list">
    <div class="element">Element_1</div>
    <div class="element">Element_2</div>
    <div class="element">Element_3</div>
    <div class="element">Element_4</div>
    <div class="element">Element_5</div>
    <div class="element">Element_6</div>
    <div class="element">Element_7</div>
  </div>

  <div class="list"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: overflow: hidden; не подходит. Мне нужно что бы самой прокрутки не было, а scroll остался.

Comment: Я заметил что при это прокрутка стала мгновенной, можно ли это как то исправить ? и Можете пожалуйста перевести код в Vanila JS.

Comment: И ещё хотел спросить я вот нашел похожий script что бы запретить scroll но почему-то при scroll выдаёт ошибку можете посмотреть с чем это связано? http://output.jsbin.com/xatidu/4/

Comment: @ПолосатыйТигр, чтобы сделать прокрутку по умолчанию, замените `scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);` на `scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно `body` задавать `overflow: hidden` и давать ему `padding-right: 17px`, так как это ширина полосы прокрутки по умолчанию. Можно не задавать `padding-right: 17px`, но при исчезновении полосы будет резкий сдвиг блоков, что неприятно глазу, а также весь body будет смещён вправо на 17px. Для мобильных телефонов и всех устройств, у которых у body по умолчанию нету прокрутки не нужно давать этот отступ. Чтобы определить это, можно пользоваться такой функцией:

```js
function whatPhone() {
    return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini|Mobile Safari|PlayBook|KFAPWI/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
//Пример кода
if (whatPhone()) {
    сonsole.log('Это телефон или устройство без полосы скролла у body, тут не надо задавать отступы для body');
}
```

Возможно эту функцию можно дополнить, но я пользуюсь сейчас таким

```js
let list = document.querySelectorAll('.list');
let list0 = list[0];
let list1 = list[1];

function whatPhone() {
 return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini|Mobile Safari|PlayBook|KFAPWI/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}

function addClassBody() {
  document.body.classList.add('active');
  if (!whatPhone()) {
    document.body.style.paddingRight = '17px';
  }
}

function removeClassBody() {
  document.body.classList.remove('active');
  if (!whatPhone()) {
    document.body.style.paddingRight = '0px';
  }
}

list0.addEventListener('mouseover', addClassBody)
list1.addEventListener('mouseover', addClassBody);
list0.addEventListener('mouseout', removeClassBody);
list1.addEventListener('mouseout', removeClassBody);
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 300vh;
    background-color: #EDEEF0;
    position: relative;
}

body.active {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
 <div class="element">Element_1</div>
 <div class="element">Element_2</div>
 <div class="element">Element_3</div>
 <div class="element">Element_4</div>
 <div class="element">Element_5</div>
 <div class="element">Element_6</div>
 <div class="element">Element_7</div>
</div>

<div class="list"></div>
```